# How to plot Heatmap confussion matrix with entire numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am plotting a confussion matrix like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
#Initalize the classifier
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
#Fitting the training data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
#Predicting on test
y_pred=clf.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

print(f'Accuracy = {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred):.2f}\nRecall = {recall_score(y_test, y_pred):.2f}\n')
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm_plot = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues');
cm_plot.set_xlabel('Predicted Values')
cm_plot.set_ylabel('Actual Values')
cm_plot.set_title('Confusion Matrix (with SMOTE)', size=16)
```

And I get this result:
[image]

But its showing numbers like 3.3e+02 when the real number confussion matrix values are like this:

```
[[327 103]
 [ 51 346]]
```

How can I plot the real numbers in the heatmap ?

Comment: I can't reproduce your example, so I cannot test, but does `cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred).round(2)` work?

Comment: This question is missing an important piece of information, namely that the heatmap is plotted with Seaborn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are plotting your heatmap with Seaborn. You can format numbers with [`seaborn.heatmap`'s](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) `fmt` argument. Doing `cm_plot = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, cmap='Blues', fmt='d')` should work.